# navigationBar of UINavigationController dissappears

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

I have this:

**FirstViewController**:

```
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

**SecondViewController**:

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];   
}
```

My problem is that when I comeback from **SecondViewController** to **FirstViewController** the NavigationBar is still hidden.Is there a way to make it appear when I'm back in **FirstViewController**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `FirstViewController.m`:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it's always possible that a different navigation controller will have set the bar to be hidden. So, in your `viewWillAppear` set the flag as follows:

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO]; 
This will do.